# Unexpected polymorphic behaviour with base class reference

Tags: java, polymorphism

I wrote this code

```
class Flower{
  String name = "Flower";
  void print(){System.out.println("Flower method");}
}

class Rose extends Flower{
  String name = "Rose";
  void print(){System.out.println("Rose method");}
}

....
//Another class in same default package
public static void main(String... args){
  Flower f = new Rose();
  f.print();
  System.out.println(f.name);
}
```

I was exepecting the output for this code to be:

```
Flower method
Flower
```

but instead it printed

```
Rose method
Flower
```

My rule of thumb was that when you use one of these 'lesser' types as a reference, only their members are visible in the object. You will need to cast to access the rest. But it seems methods are treated differently?

Comment: Since you override the parent method, it's the right behaviour. Method execution depends on runtime type. Overriding is not working with fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahaaa.. Polymorphism. One of the better features of OOP. Step by step explanation:

1. You are using single **inheritance**, where class `Rose` is **derived class** and `Flower` is the **base class**.
2. When you have, the **methods with the same name** in both your superclass and derived class , by default, the method of the derived class is called , not that of the superclass. They are `Over-ridden` by default.
3. The fields in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through super.

You get the output because :

1. `f.print()` will call method of **Rose** and not **Flower**. If you need to call the `print()` of flower you can use `super.print()` accordingly.
2. `f.name` is printing `Flower` because, the type of `f` is `Flower` and not `Rose`. You can use a method to access it like:

   ```
   public String getName()
   {
     return this.name;
   }
   ```

and use it accordingly: `System.out.println(f.getName);`

**EDIT:** To understand it in layman's terms , @Juned Ahsan's answer is very simple and clear:

```
Flower f = new Rose();
```

Since `f` is a new `Rose` , the statement `f.print()` will call the method of the `Rose`.

Thought it was worth mentioning. :)

Try reading up on polymorphism. There are tons of references. :)

Comment: I had just finished a chapter on it :) So in a nutshell, the reason my expectation was incorrect is because the polymorphic behavior applies to methods and not members.

Comment: Correct.. By default the methods are over-ridden. :)

Comment: While there were other good answers, I'm choosing this one because it directly addresses the question of the expected versus actual outcome. Thanks.

Comment: In your original you mixed a getter and a setter into a getSetter which is even worse than a jetSetter :-). Edited it so it's a pure getter.

Answer (score 2):

**fields are not polymorphic like methods**

Here the confusion with the same  field name.

[Java language specification#shadowing.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.4.1)

[Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) saying

> Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through super

So in your case the field `name`  of class `Rose` hidden  by the super calss `Flower`

Comment: But my field was not hidden, the "Flower" String member was returned. It's the method that had the override. I know that these are the official Java Docs, but I'm still confused by this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Flower f = new Rose();
```

As `f` is holding object of `Rose` so the overriden method of `Rose` will be called when called like this:

```
  f.print();
```

and will print `Rose method`

`f` is a flower reference and overriding is the concept for only `methods` and not for instance fields, hence

```
  System.out.println(f.name);
```

will print `Flower`

Answer (score 0):

you are overriding the print method of class Flower in class Rose. That is why you are getting this output .

Comment: But overriding the method is a part of polymorphism, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it appears when you are implementing inheritance i.e 'extends'.

Answer (score 0):

When you use "dynamic polymorphism", you super class reference holds  sub class object. In your case Rose object is with f.

```
Flower f = new Rose();
          f.print();
```

when you call print method, it actually calls print method in Rose class.